# Crop an image using rectangular box of selected area?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, crop

I am looking for a good tutorial or sample code, that would show how to crop an image taking from iphone camera

something in lines of

[image]

but you would control the corners with your fingers

any tip would be greatly appericated, as i tried in many way but didn't get a result.

Comment: same question who doesn't answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754618/how-to-crop-an-image-using-rectangale-overlay-and-touch-on-iphone

Comment: What did you try?  What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238464/croping-an-uiimage-using-frame-to-cut i tried this mush see this link

Comment: It may helps you : 
https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView

Comment: not able to run that file RayofHope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some changes in the button action

```
-(IBAction) cropImage:(id) sender{


        // Create rectangle that represents a cropped image  
        // from the middle of the existing image

    float xCo,yCo;

    float width=bottomCornerPoint.x-topCornerPoint.x;

    float height=bottomCornerPoint.y-topCornerPoint.y;


    if(width<0)

    width=-width;


    if(height<0)

        height=-height;


    if(topCornerPoint.x <bottomCornerPoint.x)

    {

    xCo=topCornerPoint.x;

    }

    else 
    {
            xCo=bottomCornerPoint.x;
        }


        if(topCornerPoint.y <bottomCornerPoint.y)

    {

            yCo=topCornerPoint.y;

        }


    else {

            yCo=bottomCornerPoint.y;

        }


        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xCo,yCo,width,height);

        // Create bitmap image from original image data,
        // using rectangle to specify desired crop area

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];


        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);


        // Create and show the new image from bitmap data

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 600, width, height)];

        imageView.image=img;

        [[self view] addSubview:imageView];

        [imageView release];



    }
```

Comment: @ceacare it's working fine. I have tested before pasting it here. and everyone just can help here not make the complete projects to you according to ur requirements.

Comment: okay okay i can understand anil, i'm just new to this development