# Crop image using border frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to crop image using rectangle frame. But somehow not able to do that according to its required.

Here is What i am trying:

[image]

Here is the result i want :

[image]

Now what i need is when click on done image should crop in rectangle shape exactly placed in image. I have tried few things like masking & draw image using mask image rect but no success yet.

Here is my code which is not working :

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[imgMaskImage.image CGImage];
mask.frame = imgMaskImage.frame;
imgEditedImageView.layer.mask = mask;
imgEditedImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Can anyone suggest me the better way to implement it.

I have tried so many other things & wasted time so please if i get some help that it will be great & appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252779/crop-an-image-using-rectangular-box-of-selected-area

Comment: @Immi i had already implemented the thing with square but for oval shape that i want as above screen is not working

Comment: this is not what i am looking for.

Comment: what exactly r u looking for

Comment: I mean i am not getting solution for my question from this link

Comment: Can you upload masking images separately with which you mask this image ?

Comment: yes mask image is separate image.

Comment: That I know, So, I am asking you to upload that separate images in Question as well as what you are getting it as output and what you expect to get as an out put may be then people will come to know what is going wrong

Comment: @DivineDesert ok got it i am updating question

Comment: You need to use a mask image with circle

Comment: @DivineDesert yes i did that i need to crop in oval shape. I used oval  shape image but with transparent area inner it. So how can i do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)croppedPhoto {
    // For dealing with Retina displays as well as non-Retina, we need to check
    // the scale factor, if it is available. Note that we use the size of teh cropping Rect
    // passed in, and not the size of the view we are taking a screenshot of.
         CGRect croppingRect = CGRectMake(imgMaskImage.frame.origin.x,
    imgMaskImage.frame.origin.y, imgMaskImage.frame.size.width,
    imgMaskImage.frame.size.height);

    imgMaskImage.hidden=YES;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(croppingRect.size, YES,
    [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(croppingRect.size);
    }

    // Create a graphics context and translate it the view we want to crop so
    // that even in grabbing (0,0), that origin point now represents the actual
    // cropping origin desired:
         CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
         CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -croppingRect.origin.x, -croppingRect.origin.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    // Retrieve a UIImage from the current image context:
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Return the image in a UIImageView:
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you do

```
+(UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image andMaskingImage:(UIImage *)maskingImage{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskingImage CGImage];
    CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskingImage.size.width, maskingImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (mainViewContentContext==NULL)
        return NULL;
    CGFloat ratio = 0;
    ratio = maskingImage.size.width/ image.size.width;
    if(ratio * image.size.height < maskingImage.size.height) {
        ratio = maskingImage.size.height/ image.size.height;
    } 
    CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskingImage.size.width, maskingImage.size.height}};
//// CHANGE THIS RECT ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS

        CGRect rect2  = {{-((image.size.width*ratio)-maskingImage.size.width)/2 , -((image.size.height*ratio)-maskingImage.size.height)/2}, {image.size.width*ratio, image.size.height*ratio}};
        CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
        CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, image.CGImage);
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
        CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
        CGImageRelease(newImage);
        return theImage;
    }
```

You need to have image like this

Note that 
The mask image cannot have ANY transparency. Instead, transparent areas must be white or some value between black and white. The more towards black a pixel is the less transparent it becomes.

[image]